# How to subscribe to remote events in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

If I want to subscribe to messages published on an event stream in a remote system what is the recommended approach?

So for example in one system I have the code.

```
case class MyClass(x: Int)

val es = context.system.eventStream
es.publish(MyClass(3))
```

Within this system I would just to a

```
context.system.eventStream.subscribe(self, classOf[MyClass])
```

But how do I do this in a remote system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/event-bus.html#event-stream):

> The event stream is a *local facility*, meaning that it will not distribute events to other nodes in a clustered environment (unless you subscribe a Remote Actor to the stream explicitly). If you need to broadcast events in an Akka cluster, *without* knowing your recipients explicitly (i.e. obtaining their ActorRefs), you may want to look into: [Distributed Publish Subscribe in Cluster](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/distributed-pub-sub.html).

If you can obtain the `ActorRef` of the remote actor, simply subscribe that actor to the event stream with its `ActorRef`:

```
context.system.eventStream.subscribe(remoteActorRef, classOf[MyClass])
```

Otherwise, use the Distributed Publish Subscribe capability.